# Python - copying maths questions including formulae/symbols out of a PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, utf-8

I'm attempting to read some maths questions from a number of PDFs I have, for example:

[image: PDF File]

Currently I'm using [Textract](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract)'s [process](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python_package.html), but it's giving me outputs as follows: (written in a HTML file with charset=utf-8)

[image: Textract Output]

My question is whether it's possible to extract the equations in a better format, at least one that is readable or definitely convertible to a readable format? Text would be preferable however images could also work. Cheers!

Comment: This might help you. https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

Comment: Although closer, still having issues when using pdfminer https://i.imgur.com/F7Qtszq.png (real PDF on right, pdfminer output on left)